# What is the equivalent of this Ajax code, in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

None of the jQuery methods, from the jQuery page could work in the same way, as this simply does.

```
function enableAjaxTask(removeLink){

    var xmlhttp = false;


    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
            document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }


    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'foo.php?id=22', true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);

}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: `jQuery('#foo').load('foo.php?id=22')`

Comment: What's *your* take on what it would be? Give it a go, and then if you run into trouble, ask for help and post your efforts.

Comment: Obviously OP knows a lot about Javascript, after all, none of our brains are capable of considering how his method is so far simpler than, you know, the load method... /sarcasm

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET', //GET/POST
    url: 'foo.php',//URL to send request
    data: 'id=12', //query parameters here, you can direct pass url: 'foo.php?id=12'
    success: function(responseText){ 
            //called if the request succeeds. also check complete ,done, error
        $('#foo').html(responseText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#foo").load('foo.php?id=22');
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Quite right, though this probably should have been left as an exercise for the OP.